# Rails 3.2 to 4.0 Upgrade: Undefined method to_datetime for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel, activesupport

I'm upgrading a Rails application I've inherited from 3.2 to 4.0.1.  I followed and finished the edge guide here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0

I've gotten everything fixed except for a single error that I can't seem to find the root cause of.  When I attempt to save a User model object, I'm met with the following error:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.create(name: "test user", email: "testuser@frobnitz.com", password: "testPassword123", password_confirmation: "testPassword123")                                                                                                                               

(0.6ms)  BEGIN
(0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_datetime' for false:FalseClass
from /home/cmhobbs/src/serve2perform/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:161:in `<=>'
```

`activesupport` 4.0.1 and `rals` 4.0.1 are installed.  I use chgems and I purged my `.gem/` directory and `Gemfile.lock` before bundling again.

Here is a [Gist of the User model.](https://gist.github.com/cmhobbs/fd56a869088d722face3de4057fca696)

And [here is all of the backtrace output](https://gist.github.com/cmhobbs/4f0cc2b9783b18542234d8c37c00ae39) I could get from `pry`.

Here is a [link to the User table schema](https://gist.github.com/cmhobbs/a2a858eedb5db951068eb3107adea60b).

Comment: it happen because of `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: @uzaif would you mind explaining further?  Thanks!

Comment: can you show the schema for users table. Also have you restarted the server, can you try creating a user in console

Comment: the link for the gist with the backtrace output is giving a 404 error

Comment: @cmhobbs can u post your schema for user table ?

Comment: From the stack trace it is evident that a callback (probably a before_create one) is trying to compare some dates but one of them is `false`. But it is a mystery to me what callback it is. Probably it's not one of those in `user` model but more likely a callback from a gem, perhaps devise, or something else?

Comment: What I would do is to open up the `active_support/callbacks.rb` file in `ActiveSupport` on [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L370) (see your stack trace for the precise file location) and add a debug line before it: `Rails.logger.debug "#{name} #{str}"`. This should reveal the callbacks internal name and the callbacks code. Then please paste here the debug that is printed for the callback with the same name as in your stack trace: `_run__768037688__create__callbacks`.

Comment: @coderVishal this was user creation from the console.

Comment: @BoraMa great observation.  I'll give that a try, thanks.

Comment: @BoraMa here's the requested info:  https://gist.github.com/cmhobbs/cbb92fcd9114005f5e3c05363722d546

Comment: That's odd... Feels like your DB has different schema rather than specified in `schema.rb`, but that's just a wild guess. Try to remove (comment out) pieces of code until you get smaller example to achieve the error - there's a big chance that you will find bugging piece of code pretty fast. Also, unrelated, but avoid `Time.now` and use `Time.current` (shortcut for `Time.zone.now`), or you might get into trouble :)

Comment: If you update Rails to say 4.2-ish, this problem should go away.  That said, looking at the root of the problem, it sounds like maybe your User table has a default on created_at and updated_at columns set to false ... which, as other posters said, makes no sense.

Comment: @GoGoCarl my fear with upgrading another two rails versions is the introduction of further problems.  How do I know if the default on created_at and updated_at is set to false and how do I change that to the recommended default?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, you'd be in the same boat as you are now :)  Far as checking, if you're using postgres, you should be able to do `psql -c "\d+ users" {database}`.  You can see what the makeup of the table is. But, again, doubtful (but post here if that is somehow the case!).  Most likely, perhaps, is that one of your gems is doing something odd.  One step may be to strip out extraneous gems, get the create command working, then re-introduce them one by one until you break again. If you post your Gemfile here, maybe someone can guide/shortcut that process.

Comment: not to be trollish but have you tried writing a unit test for the User class? Something that would just run the "valid?" or "save" command should be enough to flesh out if this is in the code or there is bad data in the database.

Comment: My guess is there's a problem with the callbacks. Comment out the callbacks and see if it works.

Comment: The offending line was this one:  https://gist.github.com/cmhobbs/fd56a869088d722face3de4057fca696#file-user-rb-L113  The comment by @BoraMa led to me finding it.  I'm still not sure how to fix it but that particular method feature seems to be deprecated, so I simply commented it out.  I'm not sure what the best route for submitting/accepting an answer would be at this point.

Comment: Ah, great that you found it, I think I get it now! Will post an explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you've found the offending callback to be this one:

```
  before_create :activate_license

  def activate_license
    self.active_license = true
    self.licensed_date = Time.now
  end
```

things begin to be clearer. The `activate_licence` is a *before* callback. *Before* callbacks can [**halt the whole callbacks chain by returning `false`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution) (or raising an exception).

If we look carefully in the debug output that you provided by manually adding some `puts` lines into the Rails callbacks code, we can indeed find the comparison of this callback result with false ([here](https://gist.github.com/cmhobbs/cbb92fcd9114005f5e3c05363722d546#file-logger-callbacks-L463) - I removed some unimportant parts of the code):

```
result = activate_license
halted = (result == false)
if halted
  halted_callback_hook(":activate_license")
end
```

Because the support for halting before callbacks by returning `false` (i.e. the Rails code shown above) practically has not changed from [Rails 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L182) to [Rails 4.0.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L159), the issue must lie in the comparison itself.

The callback returns a `DateTime` object (it's the last assignment in the method which is also returned). And, indeed, the comparison of `DateTime`s changed significantly between the two Rails versions (also note that the `==` operator is normally [evaluated using the `<=>` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html#method-i-3D-3D)):

- in Rails 3.2 it was [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb#L139):

  ```
  def <=>(other)
    if other.kind_of?(Infinity)
      super
    elsif other.respond_to? :to_datetime
     super other.to_datetime
    else
      nil
    end
  end
  ```

  notice especially the `respond_to?` check if the `other` object is also a date or time object while otherwise returning `nil`.
- whereas in Rails 4.0.1 this [changed to](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb#L160) the bare code below:

  ```
  def <=>(other)
    super other.to_datetime
  end
  ```

  → all **sanity checks are gone**!

Now, everything is clear: the result of the callback (a `DateTime` object) is compared using the `<=>` operator with `false` and under Rails 4.0, the comparison tries to convert the `false` object to `DateTime` without any sanity checks, which of course fails and throws the exception.

To fix this issue, simply ensure that your callback **returns something that Rails can compare with `false` without any problems**, e.g. `true`, as your callback is never supposed to halt the chain:

```
  def activate_license
    self.active_license = true
    self.licensed_date = Time.now
    true
  end
```

Now everything should work as expected again.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind even in core classes, please do something like this and check what the `other` is, from where it came from.

/home/cmhobbs/src/serve2perform/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb

```
def <=>(other)
  binding.pry
  if other.kind_of?(Infinity)
    super
  elsif other.respond_to? :to_datetime
    super other.to_datetime rescue nil
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: With overriding this in gem file, it works -> do we have any solution without using this ?